# Does Google Drive OCR images for the search internal function in Google Drive?

Tags: google-drive, ocr

I was just searching my Google Drive account for a document containing the word 'internet' and the top hit was a screenshot i took of instructions of how to configure the DNS settings to use for a proxy VPN service - which is littered with the word 'internet'

The file is named `Screen Shot 2013-06-23 at 21.29.53.png` and its a png so there is no static text in there (although it is a screen shot if text).

Does Google Drive OCR images to check for the text inside of them to make them available in search, or is this just a lucky coincidence ?

Answer (score 1):

I expect they do:   they've certainly said that they use item-recognition techniques to support image search.    (But I haven't searched for links to support articles to back this up).